# How can I add a burn function to a BSC smart contract?

Tags: smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain

University is out for summer and I am attempting to develop a smart  contract on binance smart chain.
I have followed a youtube tutorial and made a very basic token which allows buys and sells, however I would like to add a burn function i.e a tax is placed on every transaction, and I would like x% to be added to liquidity on pancakeswap, x% to be burned and x% to be redistributed to holders of my token.
The internet seems to be pretty scarce on information on how to implement this, so if anyone would mind giving me a hand it would be great!

I am creating the token on remix.ethereum.org